# Intercept theorem, sometimes getting inverse ratios..is it a problem?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

When using intercept theorem, I sometimes get confused and end up with the inverse ratios. For example:

$$ \lvert SB \rvert : \lvert SA \rvert  = \lvert SD \rvert : \lvert SC \rvert$$

instead of

$$  \lvert SA \rvert : \lvert SB \rvert = \lvert SC \rvert : \lvert SD \rvert $$

I don't think it is a problem, but I just want to be sure...

[image: Intercept theorem - Wikipedia]

Comment: Yes. If $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d}$ and $a,b,c,d \neq 0$, then $\frac{b}{a} = \frac{d}{c}$

Comment: Furthermore, we have $\lvert SA \rvert : \lvert AB \rvert = \lvert SC \rvert : \lvert CD \rvert$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, no issues...
$$\frac{SA}{SB}=\frac{SC}{SD}\iff \frac{SB}{SA}=\frac{SD}{SC}$$provided none of $SA, SB, SC, SD$ is zero.